# Background to create comic book

Tags: background, comics

I am not a graphic designer but a programmer. Recently i wrote a short story in answer of a technical question. Then I realized if i convert it into graphical comic book story then it would be more interesting and understanding.

I have many characters/pose in vector form. And am looking for some backgrounds which are generally be used in comic books like city,lab,planet,universe etc etc.

Can somebody suggest me a place/site where i can find them. I tried to bing/google them but they searched wallpaper with super heroes.

Comment: Is your comic similar to things like dilbert or xkcd? They are quite different, and the backgrounds for both are chosen well for each task.

Comment: @Christoph, sorry i am not aware with dilbert or xkcd. But this comic would be a sci fi story. But my question is general. So resource for any type of comic style backgrounds would be useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you to search specifically in google such as : cartoon city/comic city/ by this you only get background of particular city/place without any superhero

Please see this links if they may help you..

1. [Cartoon comics](http://www.marketwallpapers.com/wallpapers/azusa-background-christmas-comic-images-movietome-nodoka-pictures-ritsu-sawako-tsumugi-wallpaper-cartoon-city-comics-pubblicato-wallpaper-50850.html)
2. [Cartoon City Building](http://www.google.co.in/search?hl=en&biw=1280&bih=585&tbm=isch&sa=1&q=cartoon%20city%20buildings&oq=cartoon%20city%20&aq=1&aqi=g6g-s1g3&aql=&gs_sm=e&gs_upl=3299l3299l0l1l1l0l0l0l0l315l315l3-1)

and if you have access to photoshop its damn so easy to convert any kind of image into comic/cartoon look...

[Convert image to cartoon image with the help of photoshop](http://netparadiso.blogspot.com/2008/03/convert-any-image-into-cartoon-with.html)

Hope this will help a bit....

Comment: I observed that i was using wrong words while searching for backgrounds. If i exclude comic word and i search using "sci fi background" then i get better results.

Comment: that's good you understood.....

Answer (score 0):

In information comics I would keep backgrounds to a bare minimum, if any. If they don't contribute to information, leave them out.